# pandas: identify columns containing uuid and cast it to strings

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch, casting

### Context

I am looking for a simple way to cast columns with `uuid.UUID` values into strings. The annoying part is that `dtypes` is not very helpful:

```py
(Pdb) df.dtypes
accountid                       object
name                            object
fir_numerodedossierquadratus    object
fir_logicielcomptablename       object
fir_numerodesiret               object
fir_regroupement                object
fir_regroupementname            object
regroupemententite              object
```

However, if I look at individual values, I get

```
(Pdb) type(df["fir_regroupement"][0])
<class 'uuid.UUID'>
```

causing a JSON serializer used later to freak out. Data comes from a MSSQL table (read with `pd.read_sql`)

```
Arguments: (140188647159600, 0, 'identities', 'ElasticLoader', 1, TypeError('Object of type UUID is not JSON serializable'))
```

### Need

Sure, I could

```py
df['fir_regroupement'] = df['fir_regroupement'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
```

But I would appreciate if my app could **automatically identify** the faulty columns. While looking for '*pandas identify columns with uuid*', I do not find much. That being said, I could also look for a fix **upstream** (i.e. in `read_sql` params?) or **downstream** (i.e. using a custom serializer in [AsyncElasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/main/elasticsearch/_async/client/__init__.py#L161)) but I think that I would have less control over what's happening.

How would you identify dtype:object columns containing some type (such as `uuid.UUID`)?

Comment: Have the relevant columns only UUIDs? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Something like `df['column'].apply(type) == uuid.UUID` would indicate if any objects are of that class.

Comment: @mozway : yes, with some missing data

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own extension type for the underlying array as linked to [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-extension-types).

Last time I had this problem, I found it much quicker to just convert like you had done as there were no other functions that I needed other than to convert to string and check for null values.

Comment: Transposition to my case is not crystal clear yet. My column contains `uuid` and not `lis[uuid]` but thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following:

```
import uuid
for (columnName, columnData) in opps.iteritems():
    tstdf = df.loc[df[columnName].apply(type)  == uuid.UUID]
    if len(tstdf) > 0:
        print('Column Name : ', columnName)
        df[columnName] = df[columnName].apply(lambda x: str(x))
```

Comment: You did that and .... ? Would you like what the code achieves, why that solves the problem and how it does achieve that? Such an explanation would increase the chance that your code-only answer is perceived as a helpful answer.

Comment: Also, since python is sensitive for that, you probably want to improve the formatting, indentation of your code, with the help of this info: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help